# React array.map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mapping

I will use this example http://codepen.io/lacker/pen/vXpAgj , since it's very similar to my current issue. So, let's say we have this array:

```
[
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$49.99', stocked: true, name: 'Football'},
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$9.99', stocked: true, name: 'Baseball'},
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$29.99', stocked: false, name: 'Basketball'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$99.99', stocked: true, name: 'iPod Touch'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$399.99', stocked: false, name: 'iPhone 5'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$199.99', stocked: true, name: 'Nexus 7'}
]
```

How can I rewrite the code below using array.map()?

```
    var rows = [];
    var lastCategory = null;
    this.props.products.forEach(function(product) {
      if (product.category !== lastCategory) {
        rows.push(<ProductCategoryRow category={product.category} key={product.category} />);
      }
      rows.push(<ProductRow product={product} key={product.name} />);
      lastCategory = product.category;
    });
```

The sample below doesn't do the job properly.

```
const lastCategory = null;
const rows = this.props.products.map(function(product){     
  if (product.category !== lastCategory) {        
    return (<ProductCategoryRow category={product.category} key={product.category} />); 
  }     
 return (<ProductRow product={product} key={product.name} />); 
 lastCategory = product.category;      
});
```

Cheers and thank you,

Comment: you're never going to reach the `lastCategory = product.category` line due to the return above it

Answer (score 2):

You'll never be setting the `lastCategory` because you're always returning before that line.  Try moving it up into your block that will be ran if the category is different from the last category.

Additionally, like another answer stated, you need to return the category row in addition to the product row when you encounter a new category.

```
var lastCategory = null;
const rows = this.props.products.map(function(product){     
  if (product.category !== lastCategory) {
    lastCategory = product.category;
    return (<ProductCategoryRow category={product.category} key={product.category} />
            <ProductRow product={product} key={product.name} />); 
  }     
  return (<ProductRow product={product} key={product.name} />); 
});
```

Comment: Along with that, you also might wanna set 'lastCategory' as var instead of 'const' since you can't change a const after its value is set.

Comment: Good call! Wasn't even looking at that.  Thanks - updated :)

Comment: This still won't work - using this loop it requires the ability to push a category row followed by a product row in a single iteration. Here, you are pushing a category and will never push the following product because you have returned.

Comment: Noticed that thanks to another answer.  Have updated

Comment: Still won't work because you must return an individual or parent element not a pair of siblings like that.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and comments!

Answer (score 1):

The `forEach` method works because it is possible to push two elements onto `rows` in a single iteration, where is that is not possible when returning with `map()` because you can only return one element to be pushed during a single iteration.